# Java Jar file not sending email when ran from a batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file

All,

The following code works fine and sends email when ran from within eclipse. However when i export from eclipse as a jar file and run the following command from a batch file it gives me error. Note: there are other files in the jar file that work fine when ran from the batch file.

```
java -cp C:\Users\Administrator\Email.jar LotusNotes.SendEmail
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingE
xception
        at LotusNotes.RunBackUpSourceCopy.main(RunBackUpSourceCopy.java:49)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

SendEmail class:

```
public class SendEmail {

public  String to ;
public  String from;
public  String host;

public SendEmail(){
       to = "xyz@gmail.com";
       from = "localhost";
       host = "localhost";}



public  void send_production_email(String reportDate){

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{

       MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
       message.setSubject("Subject Line!");
       message.setText("Test email!");
       Transport.send(message);
       System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }
      catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Preparing to Send Email ...");

        SendEmail email = new SendEmail();
        email.send_production_email("test production");

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks you need to add [javax mail jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html)  to your class path.

**Edit**

```
java -cp "C:\Users\Administrator\Email.jar";"C:\Users\Administrator\ExternalJarFiles\mail.jar"; LotusNotes.SendEmail
```

Based on the comment bellow...

Comment: Hi npocmaka, I already added the following command to my classpath set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Users\Administrator\ExternalJarFiles\mail.jar;  still i get the same error please help?

Comment: but you dont use the `%CLASSPATH%` variable in your script/command..?Are you executing the same command?

Comment: @Marshell - The -cp flag overrides any %CLASSPATH% definition you've previously set which is why you have to fully reset the classpath after the -cp argument as npocmaka shows.

Comment: Thank you very much npocmaka and spadaley yes that command worked and i agree with your answers. It works fine now after i added the jar file path to the java -cp command.